# Милозвучність української мови. Закони й засоби

Tags: фонетика, милозвучність

Українці звикли пишатися тим, що їхня мова - одна й з наймилозвучніших у світі.

Професор Ющук Іван Пилипович у своєму [Практикумі з правопису і граматики української мови](http://booksshare.net/index.php?id1=4&category=lunguistics&author=ushuk-ip&book=20001&page=34) (ЮЩУК І. П. Практикум з правопису і граматики української мови.— К.: Освіта, 2012.— 270 с.) зазначає:

> Звуки в мовному потоці поєднуються не будь-як, а за певними,
>   властивими даній мові правилами, законами.
>
> Звуки в словах та реченнях організовуються так, щоб їх було легко
>   вимовляти і щоб вони були розбірливі для того, хто слухає. Це одна з
>   найважливіших умов милозвучності мови.
>
> Цій вимозі підпорядковані всі українські слова, і далеко не завжди їй
>   відповідають запозичені слова. Щоб переконатися в цьому, досить
>   вимовити вголос українське і запозичене слова: *повітряний* і
>   *аероіонізатор* (з грецької), *спонукання* і *інстинкт* (з латинської), *крапка* і *пункт* (з німецької), *охорона* і *ар’єргард*
>   (з французької), *розбійник* і *гангстер* (з англійської).

В [Українському правописі 2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/pravopys2015.htm) це питання не висвітлюється.

**Чи існує унормований перелік правил (законів) і, відповідно, засобів милозвучності української мови? І якщо так, то чим він регулюється?**

**Плекаймо!**

Comment: ось, прошу ознайомитися з [думкою](http://zbruc.eu/node/41931) щодо корисності [унормування милозвучності](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par11). В статті за посиланням наведені також посилання які зможуть вгамувати вашу цікавість щодо законів милозвучності

Comment: тобто у наведеній статті захищається думка, що нормована милозвучність - це максимум недооксиморон, але обов'яковий для всіх

Comment: @Chizh Дякую, цікава стаття. Часто буває, коли делікатно натякаєш, що *"з святом"* не характерне для української та що *"зі святом"*  милозвучніше, на тебе подивляться з-під лоба і хитро так запитають: "А де це написано? І, взагалі, милозвучність - то авторське".  От і дилема - унормовувати чи не унормовувати. А ще як бачу *"з св'ятом"*, то де й зникає моя толерантність)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Унормованого переліку правил (законів) і засобів милозвучності української мови знайти не вдалося.**

Професор Ющук І.П. у [Практикумі з правопису і граматики української мови](http://booksshare.net/index.php?id1=4&category=lunguistics&author=ushuk-ip&book=20001&page=34) виділяє такі **основні закони милозвучності української мови**:

> 1. **Українська мова уникає збігу голосних**: *вона йде* (пор. *він іде*), *буду ввечері* (пор. *був увечері*), *павук* (пор. рос.
>      *паук*), *руїна* (пор. рос. *руина*).
>
> Збіг голосних в українських словах допустимий лише на межі префікса і
>   твірної основи: *виорати*, *приозерний*, *переінакшити*.
>
> 2. **Українська мова уникає важкого для вимови збігу приголосних**: а) *запорозький* (запорож+ський), *французький* (француз+ський), *кравецький* (кравець+ський), *ткацтво* (ткач+ство); б) *їжджу* (а не “їзджу”), *щепа* (а не “счепа”), *козаччина* (а не “козацьчина”); в)
>      *радісний* (радість+ний), *проїзний* (проїзд+ний), *дошка* (а не “дощка”); г) *щастя* (а не “щасття”), *Поволжя* (а не “Поволжжя”),
>      *жовчю* (а не “жовччю” і не “жовч’ю”); ґ) *розібрати* (роз+брати), *надіслати* (над+слати), *підігріти* (під+гріти); д) *сказав усе* (а не “сказав все”), *він іде* (а не “він йде”).
> 3. **Якщо доводиться вибирати між збігом голосних і збігом приголосних, то, як правило, насамперед усуваємо збіг голосних (хай
>      навіть при цьому виникне збіг приголосних)**: *росте вглиб і вшир* (а
>      не “росте углиб і ушир”), *вірю в справедливість* (а не “вірю у
>      справедливість”).
>
> **Проте допускається збіг голосних, якщо між ними є пауза (тоді пауза важить, що й приголосний)**: а вони — утікати; *а ти— іди додому*;
>   роман-епопея Л.Толстого “*Війна і мир*”, роман І. С. Тургенева
>   “*Батьки і діти*”, (після слів війна, батьки робиться невелика пауза,
>   бо названі тут поняття протиставляються); але: *море й степ*, *гори й
>   долини* (після слів море, гори такої паузи нема).
>
> 4. **Проте, щоб уникнути важких для вимови збігів однакових приголосних, перед в, ф, св, зв, тв, дв, сф і под. навіть після
>      roлосних вживаємо у**: Сумний був час; товариші мої *пішли у військо*.
>      (Леся Українка.) На алеї парку з’явився гладкий, вусатий *дядько у
>      фартусі*, з мітлою в руках. (Л.Дмитерко.)
> 5. **В іншомовних словах та в деяких словах переважно книжного походження нема чергування у — в, і — й**: *був на Уралі*, *вступив до
>      інституту*, *виконав вправу*, *уклали угоду*.
> 6. **Відхилення від цих правил допускається лише в художній літературі, де це зумовлено вимогами ритму**: 1. Яка *упевненість в
>      ході* швидкій гримить. (В. Сосюра.) 2. Курява на *вулицях вляглась*.
>      (І. Нечуй-Левицький.) Але й тут порушення милозвучності мови небажане.

В доповнення до переліку законів Професор Ющук І.П. впорядкував **засоби милозвучності української мови**, розділивши їх на фонетичні та художні.

Так, пан професор виокремлює наступні **фонетичні засоби милозвучності мови**.

> 1. Найуживанішим засобом милозвучності мови є **чергування у — в та і — й**: *день у день*, *рука в руку*; *підняв угору*, *піднявся вгору*;
>      *степ і море*, *море й степ*; *дощ іде*, *дощ не йде*.
>
> Іноді **прийменник у набирає форм ув, уві, вві**: 1. Петриків батько
>   *був ув економії* за корівника. (Остап Вишня.) 2. Стало так легко, *як уві сні*. (Ю. Яновський.)
>
> 2. **У кінці деяких префіксів, прийменників та прислівників можуть додаватись або відкидатися голосні звуки**: *відібрати* (від + брати),
>      *переді мною — перед тобою*, з*нову промовив — знов обізвався*, *пізніше сталося — пізніш усвідомив*.
>
> **Прийменник з може мати форми із, зі, зрідка зо**: 1. І блідий місяць на ту пору *із хмари* де-де виглядав. (Т. Шевченко.) 2. Лиш де-не-де
>   прокинеться пташка, непевним голосом обізветься *зі свого* затишку.
>   (М. Коцюбинський.)
>
> 3. **Після приголосних вживаються частки би, же, після голосних — б, ж**:
>      *зробив би — зробила б*, *як же — що ж*.
> 4. **Перед приголосними вживаються форми дієслів на -ся, перед голосними — на -сь**: *дивлюся на воду — дивлюсь у воду*; *зібралися
>      всі — зібрались усі*; *повернемося вночі — повернемось уночі*.
>
> **Але після приголосних завжди пишеться -ся**: *дивишся*, *дивиться*, *дивляться*, *дивився* (і рідше—*дививсь*). 
>   **У дієприслівниках, як правило, виступає форма -сь**: *подивившись*, *звернувшись*, *дивлячись*, *зупиняючись*.

А от **художні засоби милозвучності мови**, на думку професора Ющука, такі.

> Милозвучності мови можна досягти також певним добором і розташуванням
>   слів.
>
> 1. **Будуючи речення, треба стежити, щоб на межі слів не виникали немилозвучні збіги звуків**: *ці цікаві розповіді — ці захоплюючі
>      розповіді*; *велика калюжа — здоровенна калюжа*; *вартовий вийшов —
>      вартовий подався надвір*;
>      *поривчасто дув вітер — дув поривчастий вітер*.
> 2. **Не слід допускати римування слів у прозі**: *любов людини до батьківщини — любов людини до рідної землі*; *основна тема цієї поеми
>      — у поемі говориться про*; *в показі образів троянців — у змалюванні
>      образів троянців*.
> 3. Т**реба уникати набридливого повторення однакових або близьких за вимовою звуків, звукосполучень та слів.** Наприклад, у реченні
>      (прочитайте його вголос!) “С*амовідданість, скромність, людяність і
>      принциповість Свирида підкреслюється в багатьох місцях роману*”
>      нагнітається свистячий звук [с], чотири рази підряд вжито
>      звукосполучення [ісˊтˊ], яке потім підсилено звукосполученнями [сˊлˊ1,
>      [цˊцˊ] та [сˊцˊ]. Таким чином виникло суцільне сичання. Щоб усунути цю
>      ваду, речення можна переробити так: *Свирид — самовідданий і
>      принциповий і разом з тим скромний та людяний. Це автор підкреслює в
>      багатьох місцях роману*.
> 4. **Але правильно дібрані звукові повтори в художній літературі посилюють емоційний вплив твору на читача.**