# Учора-Вчора, Установити-Встановити

Tags: чергування, software

Зауважив що iOS i Android плавно переїхали на використання *Учора* замість *Вчора*, *Установити* замість *Встановити* і т.ін.

Чи існує якась норма української мови, яка обґрунтовує такий 'зсув'?

Comment: Цьікава статььа про чергуваньа: https://zbruc.eu/node/41931

Comment: Подібне запитання про "закони" милозвучності української мови та відповідь [тут](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/505/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8)

Comment: Додав теґ [tag:software], тому що запитання стосується локалізації програмного забезпечення. Не упевнений, чи треба було так робити. Покритикуйте, будь ласка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У більшості випадків такі слова є повними синонімами (хоча є випадки, коли слова не зовсім синонімічні, наприклад *вклад*/*уклад*, *вправа*/*управа*, *вступ*/*уступ*, або зовсім не мають пари, наприклад *влада*, *учень*, *увага*).

Використання *в*/*у* в «Правописі» 2015 року регулює [§ 11 «Чергування У — В»](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par11). Якщо коротко й моїми словами, то:

- Між двома приголосними вживаємо *у*: *шуруп **у** стелі*, *день **у**чителя*, *струмок **у** яру* [зауважу, що *яр* починається з приголосного, а не з голосного, бо ми кажемо про звуки, а не про букви — ⟨**й**ар⟩].
- Між приголосним і голосним, між голосним і приголосним, між двома голосними вживаємо *в*: *інновація **в** обладнанні*, *діра **в** паркеті*, *дім **в** очереті*, *робота **в**чителя*.

  - Але! Перед словом на *в*, *льв*, *св*, *тв*, *хв* тощо вживаємо *у*: *люди **у** Львові*.
- Після паузи (крапки, коми тощо) ми не враховуємо звуки, що були до паузи, а враховуємо лише подальші звуки (перед голосним вживаємо *в*, перед приголосним вживаємо *у*): *«Остап сидів на коні. **У** повітрі лунали постріли»*, *«Дмитро замислився. **У**бивча здогадка змусила його здригнутися»*.

У [проекті «Правопису» 2018 року на с. 17](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/news/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8/2018/08/22/UkrainianSpelling.pdf#page=17) майже те саме, лише пом'якшили останній пункт мого вищенаведеного переліку — після паузи перед приголосною дозволили вживати як *у* (*«…на коні. **У** повітрі…»*, *«…замислився. **У**бивча…»*), так і *в* (*«…на коні. **В** повітрі…»*, *«…замислився. **В**бивча…»*).

Хоча багато хто сприймає це радше як рекомендації, ніж як правила. Класики часто писали де-факто всупереч ним і виходило милозвучно. Див. також статтю [«Адескриптивна прескрипція (про чергування у/в)»](https://zbruc.eu/node/41931).

Припускаю, що перекладачі iOS/Android вирішили строго слідувати «Правопису» 2015 (або ж проекту «Правопису» 2018, який хоч і лояльніший, але основним варіантом усе-таки вважає той самий, що й «Правопис» 2015). Я припускаю, що Ви кажете про випадки, коли слово *вчора*/*учора*, *встановити*/*установити* чи ін. йде **на початку речення, фрази, команди, назви кнопки чи пункту меню тощо**. У таких випадках, згідно з «Правописом» 2015 (і проект «Правопису» 2018 схиляється туди ж, хоч і формально дозволяє обидва варіанти), справді слід починати перше слово з *у*.

Answer (score 9):

Згідно з [чинним правописом](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par11) 2015 року, `У-В` є [алофонами](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD) і в багатьох випадках чергуються.
Це стосується як прийменників `у` / `в`, так і слів з префіксами `у-` та `в-`.

- Перевага надається `У` з метою уникнення збігу приголосних;
- Перевага надається `В` з метою уникнення збігу голосних;
- Чергування не відбувається у власних назвах;
- Чергування не відбувається у випадку, коли слова на `у-` та `в-` мають різне лексичне значення: *вклад/уклад, вдача/удача*, або один із двох варіантів не існує: [*установа*](http://sum.in.ua/s/ustanova) = заклад, організація; але не існує слова *встанова*.

Слова, надані автором запитання, існують в обох варіантах.

---

«Зсув», на мою думку, лише уявний.
Справа в тім, що протягом часів примусової русифікації варіант `в-` отримував незаслуговану перевагу з метою притягнути українську ближче до «стандартів язика»  окупанта (в якій такого чергування нема). Як наслідок, ми усі навчалися за підручниками, де *«вчора»* було мало не єдиною нормою.
Це ж стосувалося манери локалізації програмного забезпечення.

Лише зараз, коли вихована нова ґенерація перекладачів, оновлена локалізація  програмного забезпечення більш широко використовує слова з префіксами `у-` і послуговується правилами співзвучності там, де це потрібно.

Answer (score 2):

Коли кодифікувалася сучасна українська мова у середині 19 століття, була спроба ввести в українську абетку літеру "Ў" ([У нескладове](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%8E)), яка існує в сучасній білоруській мові і звучить як у англійській літера "W".

Але чомусь цього не сталося, хоча слів, де вона напрошується, можна нарахувати дуже багато: **У**країна/**В**країна, **у**чора/**в**чора, **в**становити/**у**становити, ді**в**чина, **в**чинок, во**в**к, кро**в**, йшо**в**, бу**в** (як і всі дієслова чол. роду мин.часу).

Comment: Не стало сьа (Білоруська пішла тут дивним шльахом), бо ье алофоном **в**, наприклад **й** теж маье зовсьим подібного алофону: нескладотворчого надкороткого **і** ьак [i̯]. Польська ж **ł** ье самостіьним звуком. Також зауваженьe: Украьинська **в** основоьу вже звучить ьак [w] (Білоруська ж ьак [v]), тому **ў** стала би [u̯] — надкоротка **у**.